# Grub superuser password is required for login on 13.10

Tags: boot, grub2, 13.10, password

According to this documentation: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Passwords, I am supposed to be able to just set the superuser password to protect the grub entries. Why is grub asking for a password when booting into Ubuntu 13.10? How do I disable that?

I added the

```
set superusers="John"
password John foo
export superusers
```

to the /etc/grub.d/40_custom

Comment: Have you set it for your user to have access - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Passwords#Protecting_Menuentries ?

Comment: there is no other user than the superuser. Do I need to add --unrestricted?

Comment: The point of setting the password is to not allow access to the computer easily. So the password would appear automatically, unless you set it not to with `menuentry 'OS, Kernel' --class ubuntu -class os --unrestricted`, as it says in the documentation... So yes :-)